# Linker undefined symbols error

Tags: c++, debugging, linker

It seems like my two files, userinterface.h

```
#ifndef USERINTERFACE_H
#define USERINTERFACE_H

#include <string>
#include "vocabcollection.h"

namespace user_interface
{
//Finds a file
//
//Returns when user selects a file
std::string findFile();

//more comments followed by functions
}

#endif
```

and userinterface.cpp,

```
#include "userinterface.h"
using namespace std;
using namespace user_interface;

string findFile()
{
    return "./";
}

//more placeholder implementations of such functions; void functions have nothing within
//the brackets
```

are giving me this slew of errors from the linker:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
make: Leaving directory `longdirectorypath'
  "user_interface::showTestResults(int, int)", referenced from:
      vocabCollection::test()      in vocabcollection.o
  "user_interface::get(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)", referenced from:
      addNewCollection()     in mainlogic.o
      loadNewCollection()     in mainlogic.o
  "user_interface::findFile()", referenced from:
      loadNewCollection()     in mainlogic.o
  "user_interface::displayMainMenu(std::vector<vocabCollection, std::allocator<vocabCollection> >)", referenced from:
      mainlogic()    in mainlogic.o
  "user_interface::getUserAction()", referenced from:
      mainlogic()    in mainlogic.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [cheapassVocab.app/Contents/MacOS/cheapassVocab] Error 1
The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building project cheapassVocab (target: Desktop)
When executing build step 'Make'
```

What's happening here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the header file, you declare the function `findFile` in the namespace `user_interface`. In the cpp file the **free function** `findFile` is defined. Yes, you are `using namespace user_interface`, but the compiler doesn't know that the `findFile` defined there belongs to `namespace user_interface`. The result of all this is that you've declared `user_interface::findFile` and defined `::findFile`. When you call `user_interface::findFile`, the linker cannot find it, since there's only the free function `findFile`.

Easily solved - cpp file:

```
#include "userinterface.h"
using namespace std;

namespace user_interface
{
    string findFile()
    {
        return "./";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot implement `findFile` like that; it really has to go in the namespace:

```
namespace user_interface
{
    string findFile()
    {
        return "./";
    }
}

or:

string user_interface::findFile()
{
    return "./";
}
```

The `using` directive is only for lookup, not for definitions - imagine what `using namespace std;` would do to all your function definitions otherwise!

Answer (score 1):

You are defining findFile in the wrong namespace.

Either

```
std::string user_interface::findFile()
{
    return "./";
}
```

or

```
namespace user_interface
{
    std::string findFile()
    {
        return "./";
    }
}
```

`using` does not affect where names are defined, it only affects how names are looked up.